# could not find DLL (built using VS 2015) in modelica

Tags: modelica, dllexport, openmodelica

I have written a simple add function and made a DLL from it in Visual studio 2015. Ignore the int return, that was not necessary, I was just trying out something.

```
#  define CLINKAGE extern "C"
#  define STDCALL __stdcall
#  define DLLFUNC __declspec(dllexport)
CLINKAGE
DLLFUNC int STDCALL ADD(int a, int b, int *c)
{
    *c = a + b;
    return *c;
}
```

When i access the same function in modelica as follows it compiles but throws an error while running.

```
function ADD
    input Integer a;
    input Integer b;
    output Integer c;

    external "C" ADD(a,b,c) annotation (
      Library = "GSE",
      Include = {"#include \"GSE\\GSE.h\"", "#include <stdlib.h>"},
      IncludeDirectory = "modelica://CrtVehicle/Resources/Include/GSE",
      LibraryDirectory = "modelica://CrtVehicle/Resources/Library/GSE");   

  end ADD;
```

The error says:
Process crashed
Simulation process failed. Exited with code -1073741515.

The DLL and the Lib are placed in the folder GSE in path shown above. I also tried including a win64 folder in between but it gave the same error.

The only way the simulation works if i place the DLL and lib in the working directory. I can't do that for other reasons. How can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Modelica Specification on LibraryDirectory only talks about the linker, not what do o when running the executable: https://specification.modelica.org/master/Ch12.html#S9.SS4
I guess this needs clarification and for now you can put the  LibraryDirectory in the PATH to run the simulation executable.